# Frames getting skipped while download RTSP using VLCJ

Tags: java, vlc, rtsp, libvlc, vlcj

I'm trying to download a video from my RTSP stream. I am able to download the video perfectly most of the time. 
But in some cases during a particular time frame, some frames are getting skipped. For Eg: a 6-sec video, I get only around 4 sec. When the frames are being skipped I get the following error:

```
MultiFramedRTPSource::doGetNextFrame1(): The total received frame size exceeds the client's buffer size (250000).  17058 bytes of trailing data will be dropped!
```

Any Solution?

Complete VLC Output :

```
00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: profile High, level 5.0

[0000000021303460] avcodec generic: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) HD Graphics 630, vendor 8086(Intel), device 5912, revision 4) for hardware decoding
[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: using SAR=1/1

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: profile High, level 5.0

MultiFramedRTPSource::doGetNextFrame1(): The total received frame size exceeds the client's buffer size (250000).  17058 bytes of trailing data will be dropped!
[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: frame I:1     Avg QP:17.27  size:265736

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: frame P:30    Avg QP:18.12  size: 29747

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: frame B:89    Avg QP:22.63  size:  3406

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  2.5% 96.7%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: mb I  I16..4: 40.8% 14.5% 44.7%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  0.5%  0.4%  P16..4: 36.4%  3.7%  3.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:54.3%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 12.9%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 8.0%  skip:79.1%  L0:38.9% L1:59.0% BI: 2.0%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: 8x8 transform intra:18.3% inter:40.4%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 65.4% 50.5% 10.4% inter: 2.9% 12.8% 0.1%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: i16 v,h,dc,p: 34% 23% 28% 15%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 20% 41%  2%  2%  3%  3%  2%  4%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 29% 18%  3%  3%  4%  4%  3%  5%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 25% 20%  2%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: ref P L0: 65.3%  3.1% 21.4% 10.2%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: ref B L0: 87.7% 11.2%  1.0%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: ref B L1: 92.7%  7.3%

[00000000212b5bc0] x264 encoder: kb/s:2922.60
```

Code to download video from RTSP :

```
String mrl = "rtsp://<URL>";
String videoName = "E:\\cam11558337161068.mp4";
String options = ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,venc=x264{cfr=16},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=" + videoName + "}";

final CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = factory.mediaPlayers().newMediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.events().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        sync.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        factory.release();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }                
    }

    @Override
    public void buffering(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newCache) {
        System.out.println("Buffering ...");
    }

    @Override
    public void playing(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        System.out.println("Playing ...");
    }

});

mediaPlayer.media().prepare(mrl, options);
mediaPlayer.controls().start();

try {
    sync.await();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the cause is related to the drop message you receive: `The total received frame size exceeds the client's buffer size (250000)`, you probably need to change the size of your RTSP frame buffer.  This is done by passing the following option:

```
"--rtsp-frame-buffer-size=500000"
```

Of course you set the size to whatever you think is appropriate.  I'm not experienced at using libVLC with the Java bindings, but I believe you can pass in constructor options when you instantiate the `MediaPlayerFactory`.  This is from some of the binding code:

```
public  MediaPlayerFactory(String... libvlcArgs) {
    this(LibVlcFactory.factory().atLeast("2.1.0").create(), libvlcArgs);
}
```

... so I believe this is where you pass in the arguments in this manner:

```
String[] args = {
  "--rtsp-frame-buffer-size", 
  "500000",
};

mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
```

There are a lot of other options available that you can pass in too.

Comment: That Worked !! Thanks! Specifying frame buffer size solves the issue. ! BTW where can we find the list of all VLC ARGS?

Comment: There is a pretty long list here (not sure if it is the complete list, but it's a lot of them): https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but LibVlcFactory used in the quoted example code no longer exists in latest version of vlcj

Comment: Now i get the full video ...But some frames are delayed i.e a partcular frame stays for 3 second...A 6 second video contains only 3 seconds which is prolonged to 6 seconds..Is there any transcoding options that needs to be modified ?

Comment: you could alternatively try --no-drop-late-frames or --drop-late-frames, as well as --no-skip-frames or --skip-frames.  If it's always the same video, is there possibly an issue with that specific video?

Comment: I tried fetching videos from rtsp with different time ranges and still i get the same problem. But this doesnot happen in all the pc . I get this frequently on a VM machine.

Comment: In my experience, libVLC processes data asynchronously and in batches (several frames at once).  This has, for me, led to sometimes odd behavior.  If you CPU is overtasked because of the VM that could certainly cause oddness

Comment: Ok, I figured out that, if the machine doesn't have a graphics card in it. The slowness issue occurs. Hence I skipped the video transcoding part.  Thanks !! :)